# python: json.dumps output in custom format

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, python-requests

I have a table `info_tbl` in postgresql

```
        Column        |          Type          | Modifiers 
----------------------+------------------------+-----------
 task_info            | character varying(100) | 
 timestamp            | date                   | 
 task_count           | integer                |
```

So I basically do fetch operation on the db "select * from info_tbl" and get the data output in json format using json.dumps. But the out put i get is something like this:

```
[
  {
    "task_info": "ABC",
    "timestamp": "2017-04-30",
    "task_count": 993
  },
  {
    "task_info": "PQR",
    "timestamp": "2017-05-31",
    "task_count": 413
  }
]
```

While what i actually desire to achieve is something like this:

```
[
  {
    "task_info": "ABC",
    "data_to_plot": [["2017-04-30", "993"],["2017-05-28", "624"],["2017-06-21", "811"]]
  },
  {
    "task_info": "PQR",
    "data_to_plot": [["2017-05-31","413"],["2017-06-16", "773"],["2017-07-21", "941"],["2017-08-30", "493"]]
  }
]
```

these outputs are just for sake of understanding hence have presented only first two records while the actual table has more than 1000s of records.
I'll be using these to plot charts.

Comment: you will have to do own method to format result - without using `json.dumps` - especially you need data organized differently. Or you have first organize data in different way.

Comment: for some reasons, i cannot change the data format (table structure) as it has other dependencies as well. i wanted to know if there's any way i could re-format the json.dumps data output again to match the desired output.

Comment: you expect too different result - you can't reformat dump as so much. You have to reorganize data to display it. You have to group some elements into lists. maybe with `pandas` would be easier to group data using `groupby()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out that @furas was right its not really a good practice to reformat a dump and hence used pandas to do the re-formatting. i thought it'll be useful for others who are also trying to prepare data as input for [HighCharts](https://www.highcharts.com/) plotting, henceforth, posting the work-around i did using pandas.

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extras import RealDictCursor

con = psycopg2.connect("dbname='yourDBname' user='yourUserName' host='yourAddressOrLocalhost' password='yourPassword'")
cur = con.cursor(cursor_factory=RealDictCursor)

query = "select * from info_tbl"
cur.execute(query)

df = pd.DataFrame(cur.fetchall(),index=None)
df['data_to_plot'] = df.apply(lambda row: [str(row['timestamp']) , row['task_count']], axis = 1)

result = df.groupby('task_info')['data_to_plot'].apply(list).reset_index().to_json(orient='records')
#result
print(json.dumps(json.loads(result),indent=2))
```

output:

```
'''
    [
      {
        "task_info": "ABC",
        "data_to_plot": [["2017-04-30", "993"],["2017-05-28", "624"],["2017-06-21", "811"]]
      },
      {
        "task_info": "PQR",
        "data_to_plot": [["2017-05-31","413"],["2017-06-16", "773"],["2017-07-21", "941"],["2017-08-30", "493"]]
      }
    ]
'''
```